# Symfony how to return all logged in Active Users

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.3

I want to return all **Logged in users** of my application and render it in my Dashboard. The `user_id` and `user_name` should be retrieved from the session (I am using an external LDAP Library for authentication)

I have created a field in the database called `lastActivity` which will contain the last login time and then I can query the database for `lastActivity`  display users logged in in the last 2 minutes.

**ActivityListener.php**

```
     <?php

namespace Bnpp\SecurityBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
//use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Acme\SecurityBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry;


/**
 * Listener that updates the last activity of the authenticated user
 */

class ActivityListener

    {
    protected $securityContext;
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }



    /**
     * Update the user "lastActivity" on each request
     * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
     */


    public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {

        // Check that the current request is a "MASTER_REQUEST"
        // Ignore any sub-request
        if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
            return;
        }

        // Check token authentication availability
        if ($this->securityContext->getToken()) {
            $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();


            if ( ($user instanceof User) && !($user->isActiveNow()) ) {
                $user->setLastActivity(new \DateTime('now'));
                $this->entityManager->flush($user);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Services.yml

```
services:
    activity_listener:
        class: Bnpp\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener
        arguments: [@security.context, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
         - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onCoreController }
```

User Entity

```
<?php

namespace Acme\SecurityBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\SecurityBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{

/**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="LASTACTIVITY", type="datetime")
     */
    private $lastActivity;


    /**
     * @return bool whether the user is active or not
     */

    public function isActiveNow()
     {

    $delay = new\DateTime('2 minutes ago');

    return($this->getlastActivity()>$delay);

       }

/**
     * Set lastActivity
     *
     * @param\Datetime $lastActivity
     * @return User
     */


    public function setlastActivity($lastActivity)
    {
        $this->lastActivity = $lastActivity;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Get lastActivity
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getlastActivity()
    {
        return $this->lastActivity;
    }




}
```

Comment: is there a question here?

Comment: the session isnt global for all users; in this case you should query your DB and select all the users who logged_in_time >= now()-5 minutes

Comment: If you are saving session data in the database, you could just get the list of active sessions from the DB and assume those users are logged in.

Comment: @Petar Zivkovic - I created a table which logs in the user_id and last_login_time. How would I query the database to display logged_in_time >= now()-5 minutes? Can you illustrate it with example code? Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a great post here: [List online users](http://www.symfony-grenoble.fr/en/238/list-online-users/).

You can create a Listener that listens on the `kernel.controller` event and updates a user field lastActivity every time a user is active. You can check `lastActivity < now()- 2 minutes` and update lastActivity timestamp.

Also: [Implementing user activity in symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248237/implementing-user-activity-in-symfony-2)

## Here is how to do it

*Note: If you're not using FOSUserBundle, see Edit below.*

<kbd>1</kbd> **Add this to your User Entity**

```
/**
 * Date/Time of the last activity
 *
 * @var \Datetime
 * @ORM\Column(name="last_activity_at", type="datetime")
 */
protected $lastActivityAt;

/**
 * @param \Datetime $lastActivityAt
 */
public function setLastActivityAt($lastActivityAt)
{
    $this->lastActivityAt = $lastActivityAt;
}

/**
 * @return \Datetime
 */
public function getLastActivityAt()
{
    return $this->lastActivityAt;
}

/**
 * @return Bool Whether the user is active or not
 */
public function isActiveNow()
{
    // Delay during wich the user will be considered as still active
    $delay = new \DateTime('2 minutes ago');

    return ( $this->getLastActivityAt() > $delay );
}
```

<kbd>2</kbd> **Create Event Listener**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

/**
 * Listener that updates the last activity of the authenticated user
 */
class ActivityListener
{
    protected $securityContext;
    protected $userManager;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    /**
    * Update the user "lastActivity" on each request
    * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
    */
    public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        // Check that the current request is a "MASTER_REQUEST"
        // Ignore any sub-request
        if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
            return;
        }

        // Check token authentication availability
        if ($this->securityContext->getToken()) {
            $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

            if ( ($user instanceof UserInterface) && !($user->isActiveNow()) ) {
                $user->setLastActivityAt(new \DateTime());
                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>3</kbd> **Declare event Listener as a service**

```
parameters:
    acme_user.activity_listener.class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener

services:
    acme_user.activity_listener:
        class: %acme_user.activity_listener.class%
        arguments: [@security.context, @fos_user.user_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onCoreController }
```

**And you're good to go!**

## Edit (without FOSUserBundle)

<kbd>1</kbd> **Add this to your User Entity**

```
Same as Step 1 Above
```

<kbd>2</kbd> **Create Event Listener**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * Listener that updates the last activity of the authenticated user
 */
class ActivityListener
{
    protected $securityContext;
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
    * Update the user "lastActivity" on each request
    * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
    */
    public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        // Check that the current request is a "MASTER_REQUEST"
        // Ignore any sub-request
        if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
            return;
        }

        // Check token authentication availability
        if ($this->securityContext->getToken()) {
            $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

            if ( ($user instanceof User) && !($user->isActiveNow()) ) {
                $user->setLastActivityAt(new \DateTime());
                $this->entityManager->flush($user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>3</kbd> **Declare event Listener as a service**

```
parameters:
    acme_user.activity_listener.class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener

services:
    acme_user.activity_listener:
        class: %acme_user.activity_listener.class%
        arguments: [@security.context, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onCoreController }
```

**And you're good to go!**

Comment: I am still struggling on how to create event listeners? Can you give me an example code how would I listen to the kernel.controller event and update the lastActivity? Should I create a service?

Comment: Thanks @Patt I have updated my question with the code. Please have a look

Comment: See my update, I tested myself and it works. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Is there a way to implement it without using the FOS UserBundle? I tried the Entity manager injection in listener service. I passed @doctrine.orm.entity_manager as an argument but it gives an error like this -                    Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Acme\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager

Comment: See my edit @CloudJedi, this is because the service for entity manager is `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` and not `@doctrine`! That's a mistake in the [blog](http://www.symfony-grenoble.fr/en/238/list-online-users/) linked to that answer. Enjoy!

Comment: @CloudJedi, I am happy to help but the idea of is that we suggest code and then you tell us what works and what doesn't. How can I help if you don't tell me what error message you get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have elloborated further. The error message is            `    ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Acme\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\sinfoc\public\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 364 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\sinfoc\public\src\Acme\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener.php line 2 `

Comment: Since Symfony2.4 you could also use `if($event->isMasterRequest()){...}` to check if the current request is a `MASTER_REQUEST`. [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#sub-requests)

Comment: Add a property "lastLogout" to the user, create a logoutlistener and save date on logout and in `isActiveNow()` you return false if there was a logout after lastActivity, so you do not see users as logged in if they logged out

Answer (score 10):

As I can't comment on posts, I'd still like to give a remark on the answer by [Mick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384374/mick) via this answer.

Since Symfony 2.6 the SecurityContext class is deprecated and, in this case, the TokenStorage class should be used instead.

Thus, the services.yml would be as follows:

```
services:
    acme_user.activity_listener:
        class: %acme_user.activity_listener.class%
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onCoreController }
```

And, instead of

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
```

One should

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
```

(also replace the SecurityContext inside the class with the TokenStorage class)

Then, on line 38, the token availability would be checked using

```
$this->tokenStorage->getToken()
```

And, on line 39, the user instance would be obtained using

```
$this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()
```

Comment: I know this is old post, but want to just correct your typo. In services.yml in arguments it should security.token_storage instead of security.context.

Answer (score 4):

In **Symfony 4** I solved the problem in the following way.

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class ActivitySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    private $em;
    private $security;

    public function __construct(
    EntityManagerInterface $em, Security $security) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onTerminate() {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();

        if (!$user->isActiveNow()) {
            $user->setLastActivityAt(new \DateTime());
            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush($user);
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return [
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::TERMINATE => [['onTerminate', 20]],
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for using an Event Subscriber. You have an error where you say `$this->em->flush($user);` That should be `$this->em->persist($user); $this->em->flush();`

Comment: @DanMeigs Thank you. I had detected it in code, but I had not modified it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Symfony 3.4**

**1. Add this to your User Entity**

`Same as Step 1 Above`

**2. Create Event Listener**

```
<?php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * Listener that updates the last activity of the authenticated user
 */
class ActivityListener
{
    protected $tokenContext;
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct(TokenyContext $tokenContext, $doctrine)
    {
        $this->tokenContext= $tokenContext;
        $this->doctrine= $doctrine;
    }

    /**
    * Update the user "lastActivity" on each request
    * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
    */
    public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        // Check that the current request is a "MASTER_REQUEST"
        // Ignore any sub-request
        if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
            return;
        }

        // Check token authentication availability
        if ($this->tokenContext->getToken()) {
            $user = $this->tokenContext->getToken()->getUser();

            if ( ($user instanceof User) && !($user->isActiveNow()) ) {
                $user->setLastActivityAt(new \DateTime());
                $this->doctrine->getManager()->flush($user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Declare event Listener as a service**

```
parameters:
    acme_user.activity_listener.class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\ActivityListener

services:
    acme_user.activity_listener:
        class: %acme_user.activity_listener.class%
        arguments: ['@security.token_storage', '@doctrine']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onCoreController }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony3.4 (4), I used *EntityManagerInterface* to update user, and *Security* to get user, following codes worked for me :

**app/config/services.yml**

```py
AppBundle\Service\ActivityListener:
    tags:
        - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'kernel.controller', method: onCoreController }
```

**Service/ActivityListener.php**

```php
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class ActivityListener
{
    private $em;
    private $security;

  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Security $security)
  {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->security = $security;
  }

  public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
  {
    // Check that the current request is a "MASTER_REQUEST"
    // Ignore any sub-request
    if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
        return;
    }

    // Check token authentication availability
    if ($this->security->getToken()) {
        $user = $this->security->getToken()->getUser();

        if ( ($user instanceof User) && !($user->isActiveNow()) ) {
            $user->setLastActivityAt(new \DateTime());
            $this->em->persist($user);
            $this->em->flush($user);
        }
    }
  }
}
```