# List users connected to the database sumfony2

Tags: symfony

I have configure FOSUserBundle and now i want to display all users connected to databse but  i don't know how to do it.
I need to create method  in controller to display the list

```
public function indexAction()
    {
         $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
         $users = $em->getRepository('RegisterUserBundle:User')->.....
        $em->flush();
    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('RegisterUserBundle:Default:index.html.twig',
    array('users' => $users

      )
    );
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issues and i 'm debutant in symfony.

Comment: What do you mean by "all users connected" ? You can get a list of users registered in the database, you could have a list of users that have done a request in the last n minutes and have not logged out yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of users that are currently active (Activity in the last n minutes), there is a tutorial here:

[Symfony how to return all logged in Active Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096689/symfony-how-to-return-all-logged-in-active-users)

This is basically adding a field:

```
protected $lastActivityAt;
```

That is updated each time a user does a request. And a function:

```
public function isActiveNow()
```

Telling if a user accessed the database recently.