# Symfony 3: How can i get a list of online users

Tags: symfony-3.1

I am using Symfony 3.0.3 and doctrine. I am trying to build a small chat app.
So I have created a field in the database called `lastActivity` which will contain the last login time. Based on that I want to know who are all the user of my app logged into to at now.

Comment: Here's your answer: [Symfony how to return all logged in Active Users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21102160/1989089)