# Display connect users with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata

I have a question about listing all connecting user with FOSUserBundle. I followed all steps on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096689/symfony-how-to-return-all-logged-in-active-users)

But when I try to log into my user profile, I got this error:

**Argument 1 passed to App\Repository\UserRepository::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in C:\wamp64\www\staff-test\vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Repository\ContainerRepositoryFactory.php on line 84**

I added just a modification on my listener:

```
<?php
namespace App\EventListener;

**use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;**
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

/**
 * Listener that updates the last activity of the authenticated user
 */
class ActivityListener
{
    protected $tokenStorage;
    protected $userManager;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $securityContext, UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    /**
    * Update the user "lastActivity" on each request
    * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
    */
    public function onCoreController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        // Check that the current request is a "MASTER_REQUEST"
        // Ignore any sub-request
        if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST) {
            return;
        }

        // Check token authentication availability
        if (**$this->tokenStorage->getToken()**) {
            **$user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();**

            if ( ($user instanceof UserInterface) && !($user->isActiveNow()) ) {
                $user->setLastActivityAt(new \DateTime());
                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my UserRepository:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository #ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    public function getActive()
    {
        // Comme vous le voyez, le délais est redondant ici, l'idéale serait de le rendre configurable via votre bundle
        $delay = new \DateTime();
        $delay->setTimestamp(strtotime('2 minutes ago'));

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.lastActivity > :delay')
            ->setParameter('delay', $delay)
        ;

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you need to extend your `UserRepository` from `ServiceEntityRepository`. `EntityRepository`s constructor is `public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Mapping\ClassMetadata $class)`.

Comment: Can you explain me more?