# Symfony 4: Logout active user by admin

Tags: php, symfony, logout, user-management

The admin user in my Symfony 4.2 application should be able to log out another (non-admin) user. I created a user login system depending on the Symfony security-bundle (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html).

Now I am building an admin dashboard where all user have to be listed with their online status (last activity).

Is there a recommended way to list active users and kill their session if needed?

I've read some posts like this: [Symfony how to return all logged in Active Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096689/symfony-how-to-return-all-logged-in-active-users). But the answers are a little bit older and are just about listing the active users.

Comment: What session handler are you using?

Comment: Good question. I did not change or install something for the session handling. So I would say "the default one", if there is a default one. I installed the user login handling by the make:user command.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good way to kill user sessions: 
use an `EventListener` with an `onKernelRequest` event. In your main code: `public function onKernelRequest(KernelEvent $event)`

```
$request = $event->getRequest();
$token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();

if ($token === null) { // somehow
        return;
}

if ($token->getUser()->isLocked() === true) {
        // you must implement a boolean flag on your user Entities, which the admins can set to false
        $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(); // default is null, therefore null
        $request->getSession()->invalidate(); // these lines will invalidate user session on next request
        return;
 }
```

Now, on to your other question: How to list users with their online status? Easy, your user Entities should implement another boolean flag, such as `isOnline` (with a getter and setter).

Next, you should create a `LoginListener` (no need to implement any interface). And in your main code:

```
public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event) {
       $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
       if ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
             // set isOnline flag === true
             // you will need to fetch the $user with the EntityManager ($this->em)
             // make sure it exists, set the flag and then
             $this->em->flush();
       }
}
```

Your third event should be a `LogoutListener`, where you will set the `isOnline flag === false`

Symfony calls a LogoutListener (as a handler) when a user requests logout.
But you can write your own:

```
class LogoutListener implements LogoutHandlerInterface {

 public function logout(Request $request, Response $response, TokenInterface $token): void
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) { /** return if user is somehow anonymous
                * this should not happen here, unless... reasons */
                return;
        }

       // else
      $username = $user->getUsername(); // each user class must implement getUsername()
      // get the entity Manager ($this->em, injected in your constructor)
      // get your User repository
      $repository = $this->em->getRepository(MyUser::class);
      $user = $repository->findOneBy(['username' => $username]); // find one by username
      $user->setIsOnline(false);
      $this->em->flush(); // done, you've recorded a logout

    }
}
```

Hope this helps. With a bit of luck, it will. Cheers! :-)

Comment: Note that if you just just set a DateTimeInterface in your Entities (such as $lastLogin), it won't help. You really need two booleans, such as: 1/ $locked (is account locked on administrator request) and 2/ $online (is user currently online - so that we know if we need to log him / her out on administrator request). Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to store the user session in the database.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html (in here is the create syntax of the database table. Also add a user_id to the table)

in framework.yml add the Pdo Session Handler.

```
session:    
    handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
    cookie_secure: auto
    cookie_samesite: lax
```

In service.yml add a listener and register the session handler

```
 # Handlers
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - !service { class: PDO, factory: 'database_connection:getWrappedConnection' }
            - { lock_mode: 1 }

    # Listeners
    App\Listener\SessionListener:
        tags:
            - {name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onRequestListener}
```

create a new listener in

```
class SessionListener
{

    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * @var SessionInterface
     */
    private $session;

    public function __construct(
        TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage,
        EntityManagerInterface $em,
        SessionInterface $session
    ) {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->em = $em;     
        $this->session = $session;
       }

    public function onRequestListener(GetResponseEvent $event): void
    {

        // If its not te master request or token is null
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest() || $this->tokenStorage->getToken() === null) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        // Check if user is logged in
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        $connection = $this->em->getConnection();

        try {
            $stmt = $connection->prepare('UPDATE `sessions` SET `user_id` = :userId WHERE `sess_id` = :sessionId');
            $stmt->execute([
                'userId' => $user->getId(),
                'sessionId' => $this->session->getId(),
            ]);
        } catch (DBALException $e) {
        }
     }
 }
```

Now just delete the sessions from this user.

```
 /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function delete(User $user): void
    {
        $sessions = $this->em->getRepository(Session::class)->findBy([
            'user' => $user,
        ]);

        foreach ($sessions as $session) {
            $this->em->remove($session);
        }

        $this->em->flush();
    }
```