# User activity in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using symfony2.3 with FOSUser Bundle.

I want to  implement user activity in symfony 2.3 ?

User activity : When User login and do any activity to every url then earned per activity point.Users and there browsing activity on the website. Activity means that they are surfing between pages.

What is the best way to implement.

How I can do this ?

Any Example ?

Same question ask by some one [Implementing user activity in symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248237/implementing-user-activity-in-symfony-2)

But not explain How I can work with event listener because I am new in this functionality.
and this user who ask this question is already know about event listener.
Please read my question carefully.

Comment: This can help you as well: [Symfony how to return all logged in users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096689/symfony-how-to-return-all-logged-in-users/21102160#21102160)

Comment: @Pazi Thanks for comment but In example not describe How I can save value for user ?  Please read my question .

Comment: @Patt Thanks for answer I see this link this is good but I have one doubt How I can Set reward point on user activity to every page ? Can you explain this ? I am very thank full to you ..

Comment: It's a duplicate. Checking for user activity is only imlementing a `kernel.request` listener. What code goes into it, is irrelevant. Get the `security.context` service in you listener and do stuff on the user.

Comment: @Pazi Thanks, Can you give me some example ?

Comment: Do you know anything about symfony and the [event listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html)?

Comment: @Pazi I know symfony2 but in event listener I am new ..